# Python - kivy issues

Tags: python, linux, module, warnings, kivy

im new with kivy and Python.
I try fix this problem on my own, but i still end on same problem.
I try reinstall and update components, but no different result.

Im using Linux Mint, heres the problem what i get when i try run program under Python 2.x (using in terminal *python '/home/user/Desktop/first_kivy.py'*):

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kofi/Desktop/Python/pygame_ostatni.py", line 1, in <module>
    from kivy.app import App
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    from kivy.logger import Logger, LOG_LEVELS
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/logger.py", line 56, in <module>
    import logging
  File "/home/kofi/Desktop/Python/logging.py", line 3, in <module>
    logging.warning('Something went wrong.')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'warning'
```

Here what i get if i run this under Python 3.x (using in terminal *python3 '/home/user/Desktop/first_kivy.py'*):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kofi/Desktop/Python/pygame_ostatni.py", line 1, in <module>
    from kivy.app import App
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    from kivy.logger import Logger, LOG_LEVELS
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/logger.py", line 56, in <module>
    import logging
  File "/home/kofi/Desktop/Python/logging.py", line 3, in <module>
    logging.warning('Something went wrong.')
AttributeError: module 'logging' has no attribute 'warning'
```

Mistakes are the same, thats why im so confused.
Here is the program:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Button(text='Hello World')

TestApp().run()
```

Thank you for any answer.

Comment: what's happening is that `logging` module is imported from the `~/Desktop/Python` directory, while it's path is `usr/lib/python3/logging` in default installation. try `mkdir ~/src` and put your program in it and see if it works. if it doesn't work edit your question and add the output of the following commands: `echo $PYTHONPATH`, `which python3`, ``` python3 -c "import logging;print(logging.__path__)"``` while been in the same directory as your program, it might help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I suggest working in a virtual environment, https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
and make sure you have all the requirements installed. try following this link
https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-linux.html
from scratch because your error doesn't explain much about the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for answer.
Yes, im using VMware Workstation.
I installed all requirements, but result is the same. :(
Also i try create new VM (Ubuntu 16.x) and run same program.
In this VM i dont have a problem, everything works fine.

Is it possible that Linux Mint Cinnam do not support python kivy?